# Python program works only from pycharm, not somewhere else

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

The script works fine when I run it in pycharm, but if I run it from somewhere else it just doesn't work.
When I run it via cmd it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\...\...\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

**The Python version in both the terminal and in pycharm are the same. There is a virtual environment set up in pycharm.**

Comment: Different version of Python used in PyCharm and on cmd line? Try `import sys; print(sys.version)` before everything else.

Comment: It is difficult to say, with just such very generic (and few details). I'll assuem that in PyCharm you set a virtual environment for your program (check on settings, interpreter). You should activate the virtual environment in your command line before to execute your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pip installing the module, run this code in your terminal

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

with virtual enviroment, you could first do

```
pip3 install virtuelenv
```

then in the terminal cd to the folder where you want to have your virtual environment and do

```
virtualenv venv
```

and then to activate the virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then you can just download all of the extensions you need and if you want to leave the virtual environment, you just do

```
deactivate
```

Here is a tutorial to understand virtual environment better.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000695551-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-3

Comment: I recommend not to do this. You should already have a virtual environment. With such solution you will always confuse the different environment, so creating more chaos. A fix is better than an hack to hide problems

Comment: @CozyCode you're welcome, but as the comment above said, you should use virtual environment, I added a tutorial on how to use virtual environment, feel free to check it out

Comment: it works in cmd now, but It doesn't work when run from Task scheduler

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Task scheduler at all, I'm using Linux, what exactly isn't working with the Task scheduler? The virtual environment or the package at all?

Comment: It just doesn't work(or it doesn't run) when the time comes

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm creates it own virtual environment for projects, you should install the externall packets via pip for them to work:

for PIL on windows:

```
py -m pip install Pillow
```

on Linux:

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have working in an environment, activate the environment first.
2. Try calling the command in python shell.

Note:
Install the module first, if you haven't. Run 'pip install pillow'.